# Determining Imaginary Part of a Complex Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm given a function $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$, where $z=x+iy$ and $0<\alpha<\frac{\omega}{\pi}<1$.  I want to determine the imaginary part of f in polar coordinates.

Letting $z=x+iy=r(cos\theta+isin\theta)$, I have that $f(z)=z^{\alpha}=r^{\alpha}(cos\theta+isin\theta)^{\alpha}$.  Further more I know that $I[f(z)]=\frac{(r*cos\theta+i*r*sin\theta)^{\alpha}-(rcos\theta-i*rsin\theta)^{\alpha}}{2i}$.  However I am still stumped how I seperate out just the imaginary part of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} 
z&=re^{i\theta}\\
f(z)=z^\alpha&=(re^{i\theta})^\alpha=r^\alpha e^{i\alpha\theta}
=r^\alpha(\cos\alpha\theta+i\sin\alpha\theta)\\
\Im (f(z))& =r^\alpha\sin\alpha\theta\qquad \blacksquare\end{align}$$

Comment: Is it $r*\alpha*sin(\alpha\theta)$ or $r^{\alpha}sin(\alpha\theta)$?

Comment: $r^\alpha$. edited. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(1)DeMoivre's theorem : For real $A$ and non-negative integer $n$ we have $(\cos A+i\sin A)^n=\cos {n A}+\sin {n A}$....(2) Hence for integers $m,n$ with $n\ne 0$ and $0\le A<2\pi $  we define the principal value of $ (\cos A+i \sin A)^{m/n}$ to be $\cos {m A/n}+i\sin {m A/n}$ . To extend this to irrational real  exponent $a$ in a way that makes $z^a$  a continuous function  of $a$ when $z\ne 0$ ,we define the principal value of $(\cos A+i \sin A)^a$ to be $\cos {a A}+i \sin {a A}$ when $a\in R$ and $0\le A<2\pi.$ As there are,for example, $17$ different $v$ satisfying $v^{17}=z=-3/5-4i/5$, it is best to specify which one you mean when you write $v=z^{1/17}$.